# Email to potential advisor after submitting an application

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states

I applied to graduate school in US about two months ago and I am still waiting for my result. I was thinking may be it is a good idea to email my potential advisor again and asked them whether they have looked at my application or what is the status of my application?

Can you please tell me how to start this email? How should I politely ask about status of my application?

Comment: It is uncommon to ask a faculty member about the status of an application as most of the time the admission staff should handlethis kind of inquiries. If the faculty has said that you can email him/her, then maybe that is fine. Otherwise, check with the admission staff.

Comment: What kind of contact did you have with this potential advisor before?  Also: [related question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18269/19607)

Comment: I told him I am interest in your research and I asked him do you accept new graduate student.

Comment: And did he reply to that?  Unless he previously showed specific interest in you as an applicant, such an email will probably not be received with much enthusiasm.  (By the way, if you don't address your comments, like @user59419, I don't know you've responded unless I view the question again.)

Comment: @Kimball. Yes, she told I will be accepting new graduate student. Please express your interest to my research group then I will look at your application more closely.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight Can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can vote it up?

Answer (score 3):

It is uncommon to ask a faculty member about the status of an application as most of the time it's the admission staff who handle this kind of inquiries. If the faculty has said that you can email him/her, then it may be fine. Otherwise, check with the admission staff.